# local storage settings reset after every launch

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm saving some settings to the local storage

```
 ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

but every time I relaunch the app and try to read the saved values they are gone.
How can I make VS remember the settings I save in local storage?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following option selected on your Debug tab for your Windows Store app project?  If so.. don't :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 things

1. When you "Rebuild" the app, it will wipe out the isolated storage regardless of how you save it.
2. You must make sure you are calling the save method on the storage object after you make your update.

I am not sure if this applies Win Runtime, but that is usually the issue with windows phone storage.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not true: "when you rebuild the app, it will wipe out the isolated storage regardless.."

Comment: So is there any way to stop VS from wiping local settings?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski - when I build my app, my local storage is retained. I am guessing there is some issue with your VS or project settings. I am not sure of what that is.